# Validating an input based on what is entered in another input - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form that has a group of 3 text_fields. I need two of them filled to make calculations. `quantity` must always be filled. If `price` is blank, then `cost` must be filled, or vice versa.

I tried this, but `price` is never nil, even though I leave it blank. I also tried `:price == nil` and `:price.blank?`, but they do the same thing.

```
# app/models/item.rb

validates_numericality_of :cost, :greater_than => 0

if :price.nil?
  validates_numericality_of :quantity, :greater_than => 0
else
  validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question is trying to define class methods based on instance variables. There's no way this will work. Also :price is just a symbol. It can never have any value beyond it's internal value. The following results in syntax errors:

```
:price = nil
:price = anything
```

Symbols are always defined and have an internal value, which is set to the text the string after the ':'. Meaning `:price.nil?` and `:price == nil` will never be true. You're getting confused because you see :price passed to other class methods. What's really happening is that those methods take the symbol and dynamically turn into an instance method name to be called, a column name when executed, or just uses it as a key in a hash.

Enough about why what you were doing doesn't work. Let's talk about how to fix it.

You want to use the if and unless clauses for [validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html). This code does exactly what you want.

```
# app/models/item.rb
validates_numericality_of :cost, :greater_than => 0

  validates_numericality_of :quantity, :greater_than => 0,
    :if => Proc.new {|item| item.price.nil?}
  validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0, 
    :unless => Proc.new {|item| item.price.nil?}
end
```

Comment: Sorry, that should have been Proc.new before the blocks. Fixed now.